# Serial terminal in emacs

Tags: linux, emacs, embedded, serial-port, gnu-screen

I'm working on and embedded system with a serial (RS232) console.  (With a Linux desktop) I would like to connect to the serial port in emacs and be able to navigate the output with my normal emacs navigation (search / copy / yank / etc )

I am currently doing this with *ansi-term* + GNU Screen.

However, I cannot get the GNU Screen navigation to my liking.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure how GNU screen fits into the equation but have a look at [serial-term](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Serial-Terminal.html).

Use <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-k</kbd> to go to char mode and <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd> to go to line mode (where your normal bindings apply).

Killing the buffer closes the port (<kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> in char mode, <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> in line mode).

Comment: Thank you, it was tricky as in «char mode» no way to look at list of bindings — I wondered how do I quit the mode.

Answer (score 1):

This page covers using screen with ansi-term under emacs: [GnuScreen](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnuScreen)